# Prevent emacs from automatically closing a window after completion

Tags: emacs

This is some variation of a problem already mentioned, but I can't figure out what exactly.

I have my frame split in three windows:

```
----------------
|       |      |
|       |------|
|       |shell |
----------------
```

When I'm typing the shell, I do "tab" to get completions. They appear in the window on the left. Then emacs doesn't close the buffer, but the entire window, and I'm left with a horizontally split screen:

```
----------------
|              |
|--------------|
| shell        |
----------------
```

I'm not sure I understand how to stop this from happening, and it's not a problem I remember ever having. My botched attempts managed to get to the state where emacs would not close the completion suggestion buffer at all, but that's not ideal either.

What can I do to have emacs normally close the completion buffer, but leave my window alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> [dedicated-mode](https://bitbucket.org/jek/dot-emacs/src/31c6d525e006/el/emacs-goodies-el/dedicated.el)

```
;; This minor mode allows you to toggle a window's "dedicated" flag.
;; When a window is "dedicated", Emacs will not select files into that
;; window. This can be quite handy since many commands will use
;; another window to show results (e.g., compilation mode, starting
;; info, etc.) A dedicated window won't be used for such a purpose.
;;
;; Dedicated buffers will have "D" shown in the mode line.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While this allows me to make sure that emacs doesn't close the left window, now it closes the top right window, which is not much of an improvement. I don't want emacs closing any window at all, if it's going to use an existing one.

Comment: Actually I realized this was from a previous hack that automatically did "close-window-on" for the "*Completions*" buffer. I changed that to "kill-buffer" and now I no longer have that problem. Your suggestion of using "dedicated-mode" is now very useful to ensure that *Completions* doesn't open on a buffer that I would like to keep at view at all times, so thanks and I'm accepting your answer :)